# Usage of Google Tag Manager on Websites with authentication

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a website and it is not an open-to-all application (It requires authentication).

Just wanted to know if I can use **Google Tag Manager** on these type of applications ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as technology is concerned you can use GTM as long as you can make requests to the internet (which is usually the case even in authenticated applications, unless you run them locally or in a restricted company network).

Since GTM makes it easy to enter JavaScript code or links to external resources you need to be extra careful as to not compromise security on your site. Since Tag Management Systems tend to be use by non-developers they are often not aware that tags they use might have security implications (i.e. Javascript code that is inserted via GTM runs in page context and has access to a users cookies, form entries etc. and can impersonate a given user). So be restrictive in your permissions and have a developer look over things before you publish them.

Answer (score 0):

GTM does not care about Authorization, it's just a JS Library essentially, and as long as the client is connected to the internet it is possible to send data to Google Analytics or other Analytics tools using GTM.